# Do I have to worry about integer values assigned to TList become invalid?

Tags: delphi

Lets say I have the following procedure, I have the following questions marked as Q1, Q2, and so on in the comments of the code:

```
var
  winHandle: THandle;
...
// At this point, assume aList is empty.
winHandle := FindWindow(...);
aList.Add(Pointer(winHandle));
// Now THandle(aList[0]) = winHandle.

// After this point, variable `winHandle` will go out of scope thus become invalid, so:
// Q1: Do I have to worry about that the value of THandle(aList[0])
//     will be erased in the memory thus become invalid?
// Q2: If yes, what can I do to keep the validity of the value of THandle(aList[0])?
// Q3: If not, do I have to free the memory of THandle(aList[0]) when freeing aList?
```

I think I lack some of the knowledge about Delphi's memory management. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1 No. An integer is a value type. When you assign an integer, you take a copy of its value. As it happens, in this case, `TList` accepts `Pointer`, but `Pointer` is simply an address, a value type, and conceptually treated identically as an integer value type for the purpose of assignment.

Q3 You do not have to free any memory because the integers are values rather than references.

Comment: Thanks David. Re Q1 I think my confusion comes from `aList.Add(Pointer(winHandle))`, because in my eyes there is no "assignment of an integer value", but only "take the address of an integer value which will soon become invalid after existing the procedure". I think I still need to clarify my thoughts a little bit...

Comment: No. The code doesn't take the address of anything. It makes an assignment of a value type. You pass the value as the argument to `Add`, and internally the list instance takes a copy of that value.

Comment: To clarify: The value in aList[0] is still a valid integer, but it does not represent a valid window handle anymore.

Comment: @Uwe Wrong. It represents a valid window handle until that window is destroyed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan After some thoughts, now I understand the "value assignment" happens between `winHandle` and the parameter of the `Add` procedure.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan but now the derived question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59344300/will-tlist-addpointersomeint64value-possibly-cause-value-loss :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I am referring to the part following the comment "After this point, winHandle will become invalid" where all the questions are based upon. I interpret this as the window that winhandle references is destroyed.

Comment: @UweRaabe by that line actual I wanted to say "winHandle will go out of scope thus the original space it occupied will become reusable by the system and might be overwritten".

Comment: So you are happy with this question? I should say though, that you should avoid the casts and use a generic list.

Comment: OK, in that case I misinterpreted that. Davids comment holds true then.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm happy with your answer and my following thoughts which resulted in my better understanding of the things. In this case I can use `TList<>` but in some cases I want to avoid it when I need smaller EXE size (https://delphisorcery.blogspot.com/2014/03/why-delphi-generics-are-annoying.html), better customization of child classes, etc.

Comment: Smaller EXE size is actually not the primary goal, but flexibility is. I have an enhanced child class of TList, which adds a bunch of methods.

Comment: Easy to implement ghat generically I imagine