# Will TList.Add(Pointer(someInt64Value)) possibly cause value loss?

Tags: delphi

With the following Delphi code:

```
var
  myInt64Value: Int64;
  list: TList;
...
  myInt64Value := High(Int64);
  list.Add(Pointer(myInt64Value));
```

Question - Will `list.Add(Pointer(myInt64Value))` cause value loss when **compiling for Win32** platform?

I'm asking this because `TList` internally uses an `array of Pointer` to store the values, and on a 32bit platform the length of the `Pointer` type is 4 bytes while the `Int64` type's length is 8 bytes. So will the casting that happens when executing `Pointer(myInt64Value)` cause value loss if the value of myInt64Value is larger than `High(NativeInt)` (`NativeInt` has the same length of `Pointer` if I understand it correctly)?

## **Update 1**

I coded a testing project and it shows that the answer is YES - will cause value loss. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Testing code:

```
program TestInt64ToPointerCastingPrj;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes;

var
  list: TList;
  myInt: NativeInt;
  myInt64: Int64;
begin

  list := TList.Create;
  try

    // Test NativeInt value to Pointer casting
    myInt := High(NativeInt);
    WriteLn('High(NativeInt) : ' + IntToStr(myInt));
    list.Add(Pointer(myInt));
    WriteLn('NativeInt(list[0]) : ' + IntToStr(NativeInt(list[0])));

    // Test Int64 value to Pointer casting
    myInt64 := High(Int64);
    WriteLn('High(Int64) : ' + IntToStr(myInt64));
    list.Add(Pointer(myInt64));
    WriteLn('Int64(list[1]) : ' + IntToStr(Int64(list[1])));

  finally  
    list.Free;
  end;

  ReadLn;

end.
```

Testing Result:

```
High(NativeInt) : 2147483647
NativeInt(list[0]) : 2147483647
High(Int64) : 9223372036854775807
Int64(list[1]) : 4294967295
```

Comment: The pointer and the list is a red herring. If you coerce a 64-bit number into a 32-bit type you will lose half the bits, that's it. The answer is yes, if will cause a loss of value if the 64-bit value have any of the bits that is lost set before the coercion.

Comment: A side question from me, since it's been a while since I programmed in Delphi. Will the runtime throw an exception in that case or will it silently do the coercion? I ask because if it throws an exception, then *no* there will not be a loss of value, but the code won't work either, just for a different reason.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen (at least with default compiler settings) the casting will be performed silently without raising an exception.

Comment: @Edwin: Regarding your update, I am sure you know this already, but in real code you must always use `try..finally` to protect object instances (and any other kind of resources, states, etc.). I'll edit your Q to include those lines, just to make sure we don't tempt new Delphi developers into believing they are ever optional.

Comment: As @David Heffernan already asked in a comment to your last question: why don't you use a generic ``TList`` to avoid the casts and pointer difficulties!?

Comment: @DelphiCoder, That's another question, but I'm happy to answer - I want smaller EXE size, better compiler/IDE/code completion support, and better class customization.

Comment: BTW, I don't understand the downvote, isn't it a valid Delphi programming question?

Comment: It wasn't me. :) But I don't understand your concerns about using generics. The resulting EXE would be bigger, but how much? Does the difference realy matter that much? And how does it affect the other points you mentioned? I'm not aware of any negtativ effects when using generics. Compiler support, e.g., would be better because of type safety when using a generic ``TList<T>`` instead of a normal ``TList``!

Comment: The question basically boils down to "can I fit 8 bytes to 4 bytes?", not particularly a Delphi question.

Comment: BTW, doesn't seem to have been mentioned yet, you can use pointers. A pointer to a 64bit data type is pointer sized.

Comment: @DelphiCoder Re negative effects of using Generics, A) https://delphisorcery.blogspot.com/2014/03/why-delphi-generics-are-annoying.html, B) https://www.google.com/?q=delphi+generics+internal+compiler+error, C) Click + mouse click won't jump to the source, and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this will, in general, lead to loss of data.

As you say, in a 32-bit application, a pointer is 32 bits, so a pointer variable cannot possibly store a general 64-bit integer value. Only if the 64-bit value *happens* to lie within the 32-bit range will it be preserved; otherwise, you lose data. As you know, `High(Int64)` is way beyond the 32-bit range.

Comment: "*Only if the 64-bit value happens to lie within the 32-bit range will it be preserved; otherwise, you lose data*" - that is important to note, because based on the OP's [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59342365/), this may be a case where the  `Int64` variables hold 32bit values (from a `THandle` returned  from `FindWindow()`, because [Win32 handles don't exceed 32bit values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/interprocess-communication) so they can freely be shared between 32bit and 64bit processes).